# Java- Calling a method to change the color of an Oval

Tags: java, jpanel, graphics2d

1.This is part of a bigger game. I want to call the  methods to create and display the Jpanel, then be able to call the displayColors method(based on events in other classes) with an integer to change the color of the circle rendered. I've come across a repaint() method that seems helpful, but am unsure how to use it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class SimonView extends JPanel {

    public Graphics2D showSimonsColor;

    public void displayScreen() {

        //Setting up the container
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Color Game");
        JLabel mitaLabel = new JLabel("A Changing Circle");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(mitaLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SimonView());
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //just to test the display colors method. Pauses for 5 secs
        SimonView sv = new SimonView();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            sv.displayColors(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        showSimonsColor = (Graphics2D) g;
        showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        showSimonsColor.fillOval(75, 75, 500, 500);
    }

    public void displayColors(int color)  {

        switch (color)  {

            case 0: showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 1: showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2: showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case 3: showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 4: showSimonsColor.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        SimonView sv = new SimonView();
        sv.displayScreen();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You create three different instance of `SimonView`, none of which have any thing to with each other and only one which is actually displayed on the screen
2. You should call `repaint` to request that you component be repainted (after you've made some change which requires a repaint)
3. You should not be maintaining a reference to the `Graphics2D` object, but should instead be painting the current state of the component from within your `paint` when it's called.  This would mean that you will need to maintain a reference to the current color your want to use
4. You should avoid overriding `paint` where you can, lots of fun reasons, but it's just simpler to use `paintComponent` instead
5. You should be calling `super.paint` (or `super.paintComponent` if you overrode it instead) to preserve the paint chain
6. You should use a Swing `Timer` to perform time delayed actions within Swing, it's safer to update the UI and won't block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from performing updates
7. You should be starting your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this just reduces potential issues with thread deadlocks on some systems

Have a look at

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be to create a method which takes a color as an input and creates an oval with that color, returning the colored oval. When you add this oval to the panel, it will erase and redraw the old one, therefore changing the color.